# How do I send messages to a Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have created a Telegram Bot. As per the docs - https://core.telegram.org/bots any other telegram user can send messages to the bot

> Users can interact with bots in two ways:

```
Send messages and commands to bots by opening a chat with them or by adding them to groups.
```

Now other users are being allowed to send messages, but those messages do not show on the bot chat. Am I missing to configure something?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Do you mean that you are unable to see the messages sent to the bot?

Comment: @mhovd yes correct

Comment: I don't have much experience with telegram bots, but to me that sounds intentional. As an end user I would prefer for the developer not to be able to see the messages I send to a bot.

Comment: @mhovd a bot is an entity by itself. Like the Telegram excerpt says, anyone can talk to it and the bot can reply through the admin. In this case I am the bot admin, so i should be ideally be able to see the messages as well reply. If not me, who can see these messages?